# Reading data from JSON and display in html

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, getjson

I want to read and display data from an external JSON file and display it using HTML.

What I have so far:

Javascript:

```
var xmlhttpRoles = new XMLHttpRequest();
var urlRoles = "../portal/getResults.php";

xmlhttpRoles.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttpRoles.readyState == 4 && xmlhttpRoles.status == 200) {
        var rolesArray = JSON.parse(xmlhttpRoles.responseText);
        functionRoles(rolesArray);
    }
};
xmlhttpRoles.open("GET", urlRoles, true);
xmlhttpRoles.send();

function functionRoles(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    alert(arr);
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<p>' + arr.results[i].Title +'</p>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id02").innerHTML = out;
}
```

getResults.php file output:

```
{

"results": [
    {
        "DocId": 2204,
        "Title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur",
        "Locations": [
            {
                "State": "New York",
                "City": ""
            },
            {
                "State": "New York",
                "City": "New York City"
            }
        ],
        "Topics": [
            3,
            7,
            11
        ],
        "PublicationYear": "2011",
        "Organization": "New  Yorks Times",
        "WebLocation": "www.google.com",
        "Description": "Lorem Ipsum"
    }
],
"TotalMatches": 1

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="id02"></div>
```

I have been trying to get the value of title or any other element for that matter and have been unsuccessful. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The JSON you posted is invalid.

Comment: I've edited it now. Sorry about that.

Comment: are you getting as far as the alert? is the data ok at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON is an object and objects has no length property. I think that you need to change the for condition:

```js
for(i = 0; i < arr.results.length; i++) {
    out += '<p>' + arr.results[i].Title +'</p>';
}
```

Comment: @user3715910 this looks right. and to access TotalMatches you'll need to use arr.TotalMatches

Comment: This worked! The previous for condition had worked when the json was :
    [{"ID":1,"PublicationYear":"N\/A "},{"ID":2,"PublicationYear":"2016"},    {"ID":3,"PublicationYear":"2013"},{"ID":4,"PublicationYear":"2012"},    {"ID":39,"PublicationYear":"1975"},{"ID":40,"PublicationYear":"1972"}]

So I was trying the same method. Thanks for the answer!